# Auto login in CakePHP 4

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Can you help me please how to auto login into CakePHP 4.2 app?

My approach was like:

```
$authUser = $this->Users->get('2')->toArray();
$this->Auth->setUser($authUser);
$this->redirect(['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);
exit;
```

... but error is:

```
Call to a member function setUser() on null
```

Just to mention, that there is user with id 2 in table Users.

Can you help me with this please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: In what context are you doing this? (Controller, model, etc.) Are you using the old auth component or the new plugin for authentication?

Comment: I'm using new plugin for authentication. I have to allow user to login into application using link he will receive in email.

Comment: `$this->Auth` is for the old component. The new one is `$this->Authentication`, and I think the function you want now is `setIdentity`, not `setUser`.